pattern within autocorrelation confidence intervals
I have a time-series producing the following auto & partial correlation plots.
What insights can we make when there are oscillatory patterns within the grey region of insignificance? Does it make sense to use tighter confidence intervals even tho the auto correlation does not appear random?


Just noticed this similar question on stats.stackexchange.com
